# Express the formula in the form of $a+b\sqrt c$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Express these formulas in the form of $a+b\sqrt c$:

1. $(\sqrt3+1)^2$,
2. $(2+\sqrt3)(1-2\sqrt3)$.

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far? This looks like homework - I'm not sure what the homework policy on Math.SE is, but I believe on SE in general we will not just solve homework problems directly for people.

Comment: How is this related to abstract algebra?

Comment: Well tbh I'm not a math guy. I'm just trying to solve some questions I got, to learn maths. Would be a big help if anyone can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Using $(a+b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2$ we get $(\sqrt3 + 1)^2$ as $3 + 1 + 2\sqrt3 = 4 + 2\sqrt3$
2. Using the distributive property we get $(2 + \sqrt3)(1 - 2\sqrt3) = 2(1 - 2\sqrt3) + \sqrt3(1 - 2\sqrt3) = 2 - 4\sqrt3 + \sqrt3 - 6 = -4 - 3\sqrt3 = -(4+3\sqrt3)$.

Both of the equation are in the form $a + b\sqrt(c)$.

Hope it helps

Comment: [Not all questions can or should be answered](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), in principle, only well-asked ones should be. "Well-asked" only include those questions where the OP has made an effort to provide context, or at least an indication that an unsuccessful attempt was made. This is not the case here. See [this thread on meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards) for more information.